# Postgres - Select items with a user_id of NULL if a row with the supplied user_id does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `item_metadata(item_id, item_name, user_id)`.
I'm storing the same `item_id` with custom names depending on the `user_id`, and I'd like to have a "default" name if there is no custom name available.

```
item_id | item_name       | user_id
001     | 'Default Name'  | NULL
001     | 'Custom Name'   | 100
```

Given the above, I'd like my query to return `'Custom Name'` if I pass in `100` as the `user_id` parameter, but to return `'Default Name'` if I pass in `101` as the `user_id` parameter.

I've tried using `COALESCE`, `UNION` / `INTERSECT` / `EXCEPT` but I can't seem to get the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Could you post the queries you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this reads stuff into your question, so if it does not fit your situation, then please say so in the comments, and I will delete it.

I have encountered situations where an item has a default name but we want to show a custom name for particular users.

Modeled thus:

**Schema (PostgreSQL v11)**

```
create table item (
  id int primary key,
  default_name text
);

create table user_tab (
  id int primary key,
  user_name text
);

create table item_user_name_override (
  item_id int references item(id),
  user_id int references user_tab(id),
  custom_name text
);

insert into user_tab values (1, 'special_user'), (2, 'regular_guy');
insert into item values (1, 'Item 1'), (2, 'Item 2'), (3, 'Item 3');
insert into item_user_name_override values (1, 1, 'Special Name for Item 1');
```

---

**Extract all User/Item Pairs**

```
select u.user_name, i.id as item_id, 
       coalesce(no.custom_name, i.default_name) as item_name
  from user_tab u
 cross join item i
  left join item_user_name_override no 
   on no.item_id = i.id and no.user_id = u.id
 order by i.id, u.id 
;
```

```
| user_name    | item_id | item_name               |
| ------------ | ------- | ----------------------- |
| special_user | 1       | Special Name for Item 1 |
| regular_guy  | 1       | Item 1                  |
| special_user | 2       | Item 2                  |
| regular_guy  | 2       | Item 2                  |
| special_user | 3       | Item 3                  |
| regular_guy  | 3       | Item 3                  |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bsMwUp35gL7SBcHvSiRweh/0)

Comment: I was trying to do this all in one table, but this solution works great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `coalesce()` like this:

```
select coalesce(
  (select item_name from item_metadata where user_id = ?),
  (select item_name from item_metadata where user_id is null)
  ) item_name;
```

Replace `?` with the `user_id` that you search for.

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mEPAdYDapox2segnwPxnW1/2).

Answer (score 0):

If you want this for one item:

```
select t.*
from t
where item_id = '001'  and
      (user_id = 100 or user_id is null)
order by (user_id is not null)::int desc;
```

If you want this for all items, use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (item_id) t.*
from t
where user_id = 100 or user_id is null
order by item_id, (user_id is not null)::int desc;
```